# How to create a javascript widget to load recent posts from my wordpress site and display in other sites?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, widget

I have a WordPress site. I want to allow others to place a web widget in their website which grabs recent posts from my site and display title with a link to its page for each of my recent posts. I know that this is possible through using iframe. But this has no positive effect on my website SEO. I found a solution [here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/#putting-things-together) to use JavaScript for similar purpose. But it used Python and JSON to load HTML from the original site in the main() function. I am not familiar with JSON and Python. Is there any solution that I can return my recent posts using PHP and put it in the main function?

Comment: You can file_get_contents in PHP and echo what you need or `wp_remote_fopen($url);`

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, please take a look at the link I provided in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I use [SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie) to get RSS feeds. This is the function I use.

```
function start_rss(){
$urls = array(
    0 => 'http://ogmarketreport.com',
    1 => 'http://petroriveroil.com/feed/'
);
$numberOfPosts = 10;

foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    $url = $value;
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_cache_location($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache/');
    $feed->set_feed_url($url);
    $feed->set_stupidly_fast(true);
    $feed->init();
    $feed->handle_content_type();
    $blog_title =  $feed->get_title();
    $blog_title_url = '<div class="row" style="width: 100%; display: block;"><h2><a href="<?php $feed->get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php $title; ?></a></h2></div>';
    $blog_desc = $feed->get_description();
    $html = "";
    $x = $feed->get_items(0, $numberOfPosts);

    $html .= '<div class="container" style="width: 100%; display: block;"><h2><a target="_blank" href="' .$feed->get_permalink() . '">' . $feed->get_title() . '</a></h2></div>';

    if (count($x) == 0 ) {
        $html .= '<article class="rss col-md-12">'; 
        $html .= '<p class="danger">No Recent Posts.</p>';  
        $html .= '</article>';
    } else {
        foreach ($x as $item) {
            $html .= '<article class="rss col-md-12">'; 
            $html .= '<h4 class="title">';
            $html .= '<a href="' .$item->get_permalink() . '">' .$item->get_title() . '</a>' ;
            $html .= '</h4>';
            $html .= '<p>';
            $html .= $item->get_description();
            $html .= '</p>';
            $html .= '<p><small>';  
            $html .= "Posted on ";
            $html .= $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a');
            $html .= '</small></p>';
            $html .= '</article>';  
        }

    }
    print_r($html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But your code throws an error in my browser, Not only in the wrong arrow function (I changed => to >=) but in the line 8 which it says "missing )" and I do not know what's the problem. I am beginner with JS. Can you test your code, please?